# sshpass : how to comeout of a session

Tags: sshpass

I am remotely running some commands on a `VM`. using `sshpass` in my script but i am not able to come out of a session after script's execution. it just hangs at the remote screen ( see below)

```
//script code 
sshpass -p admin sh -T admin@10.10.10.X
ssh pass -p admin ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@10.10.10.X

----
<some more remote command>

end of script
----



//script execution

ansible-playbooks/roles/DCN-VSC/files# ./vsc_ops.sh admin 10.10.10.X 10.10.10.25 10.10.10.25 vsc:password@vsd.helion.org
XXXXXXXXXXX-76 cpm/i386  VSX Copyright (c) 2000-2015
All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements.
Built on Thu Jan 15 21:32:52 PST 2015 [c4263c] by builder in /rel3.0-DC/oem/4-OEM-76/paXX/main
```

above is remote console>

Comment: no actually i want to come back to host session after execution of script...and i don't want to hit any key manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use sshpass?

It makes it too easy to ruin SSH's security. Have you considered using other password less approaches? SSH's public key authentication maybe?

Comment: Yes , actually i don't have key facility aviaalble on the remote host so i have to live with password ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exit code at the end of the execution like :
exit 0